# How to add a custom field in checkout form in magento 2 with database entry

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to add a new field job number after email in checkout form magento 2.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM8bA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new block and template in a custom module and place it into the checkout page. Here is an example that you can put in `checkout_index_index.xml`. You would create this `checkout_index_index.xml` inside your new module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.root">
         <block name="job.custom" template="CustomModule::job/job_field.phtml" class="Custom\Module\Block\Job" before="-"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
  </page>
```

Depending on where you want to put the field, you can use the before or after tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    /**
     * Upgrades DB schema for a module
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quoteAddressTable = 'quote';
        $orderTable = 'sales_order';

        //Quote address table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($quoteAddressTable),
                'custom_test',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Test'
                ]
            );
        //Order address table
        $setup->getConnection()
            ->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable($orderTable),
                'custom_test',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Custom Test'

                ]
            );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Add our custom field to checkout page **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Our custom test fieldset here-->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="customer_test" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">300</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create **fieldset.xml**

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/fieldset.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
    <scope id="global">
        <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
            <field name="custom_test">
                <aspect name="to_order" />
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </scope>
</config>
```

**Don't forget to create registration.php and etc/module.xml**

**app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```